# Nested queries with graphql schema language

Tags: javascript, node.js, graphql, graphql-js

I have the following in my buildSchema:

```
type User {
  id: ID
  firstname: String
  age : Int
  company : Company
}

type Company {
  id: ID
  name: String
  description : String
}


type RootQuery {
  user(id: ID): User
}
```

When making this request:

```
user(id:"1"){
  firstname,
  company{
    id,
    name
  }
}
```

company is returning a null value:

```
{
  "data": {
    "user": {
      "firstname": "Jhoni",
      "company": null
    }
  }
}
```

How can I get the company value?

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow !. Everything is right, Are you having data for company ? Check your resolver

Answer (score 0):

The problem here will be to do with what data is coming into your query. The execution itself is successful, but you are not getting the company data for some reason.

To debug this, I would look at what data is actually returned in your resolver for the user query by the request. It could be the reference ID parameter is not linking to any results in where you store company details.

I guess one other possibility is that you may have may not pass back the company data into a parameter named 'company', again, looking at the object that is returned to the resolver for 'user' before it is returned by the function should give you an idea of what's not matching up.